# XMR Claymore Low Hashrate Gigabyte R7 360

Tags: mining-pools, mining, gpu-mining, hashrate, mining-hardware

I was using Claymore 9.7 on a Gigabyte R7-360 GPU on an intel-based motherboard. I've got around 190 h/s with its default gpu clock speed of 1200 MHz.

Yesterday, we removed the card to make room for an used Nvidia GT-520 and the R7-360 was installed in another CPU, this time we're talking about an AMD-based motherboard. I then ran Claymore 9.7, same settings and got just 10 h/s.

I don't have the full specs of the PC at hand...but in advance i'd like to ask what could be possibly going on with this extremely low hashrate?

Edit: After reassembling the PC, restarting and waiting for the ISP to fix their service, the hashrate came back up. I could elaborate and assume this was due to a combination of power issues and low bandwidth issues. I got the GPU working at 210 h/s.